# Pass by reference dependency injection

Tags: design-patterns, dependency-injection, reference, global-variables, state

I'm trying to understand dependency injection from the point of view of ["Global state is evil"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil). Global state could be avoided by dependency injection as the dependency is then only allowed to be modified in the local scope of a function/class the dependency is injected into. This holds true if the dependency is passed in by value.

But passing the dependency by reference/pointer would still allow other parts/systems to change the state of the dependency injected during its lifetime in the class/function it is injected into.

Is passing by reference an incorrect way of injecting dependency? Should we own the dependency through a unique_ptr as in C++? (whats the alternative in Java?) What is the correct way of injecting dependency and how can we avoid having to reason about gloabl state beyond the lexical scope of the dependency that is injected?

Comment: I have seen Spring beans used as global state; so if beans are mutable, it's definitely a concern. Immutable beans are obviously preferable, from the perspective of avoiding global state.

Comment: Just because an object is referenced by multiple other objects does not make it global. Being able to be referenced from *any* part of your module/project would make it global. If mutation is a worry, inject copies to prevent sharing references.